# Iphone SDK: How to Countdown from current time to a specific day in the future

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have was wondering how it would be possible to show the specific time remaining for a date in the future.

This is what i have so far. I can get the current time, and display that, and i used the minutes to midnight tutorial to figure out how to find out what time it will be midnight. But i am suck as to finding out how i would pick a day in the future and find out how much time is left there.

code:

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:now];

    NSInteger hour = 23 - [dateComponents hour];
    NSInteger minute = 59 - [dateComponents minute];
    NSInteger second = 59 - [dateComponents second];
    [gregorian release];
    countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second];
```

Any possibility someone could take a look at this and change it up a bit? It would be easiest for me to follow if i could understand it from using some of this code, but if thats not possible or correct I would rather know the right way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of these, it will be number of second between the two dates in double:

```
 NSTimeInterval timeBetweenThenAndNow = [futureDate timeIntervalSinceNow];  
 NSTimeInterval timeBetweenThenAndMidnight = [futureDate timeIntervalSinceDate: myMidnightDate];
```

Comment: Sorry to misunderstand but could you be more specific as to where i should try these?

Comment: You should use these to obtain the length of time between one date and another, or between now and another date. NSDateFormatter will help with printing the result, which is a NSTimeInterval - the number of seconds between. Take a look at the class references, and tell me a bit more about what you're trying to do if you are still stuck.

Comment: ok, hmm still a little stuck, but I think I know what needs to happen I just missing it when I try to put it together. I need to define two separate dates. One will be the current time which I can get by using this? -- NSDate* now = [NSDate date]; -- then I need to set a date in the future say September 15, 2010 (which might look something like this? -- NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"]; NSString *future = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"09/15/2010 12:00:00 am"]; --) I guess an example would help.

Comment: You're almost there with the dateformatter, take a look at the class reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html the idea is if you want the difference between now and your future date, don't bother making the *now date, just use [futureDate timeIntervalSinceNow];